# Caliburn.Micro, MVVM and Business layer

Tags: mvvm, navigation, caliburn.micro

I'm building a WPF application using MVVM pattern, and Caliburn.Micro is the framework choice to boost  up the development.

Different from a conventional MVVM-based application, I add a business layer (BL) below the ViewModel (VM) layer to handle logic for specific business cases. VM is left  with data binding and simple conversion/presentation logic. Below BL is an extra Data Access layer (DAL) that encapsulates the Data model (DM) underneath built with `Entity Framework`.

I'm pretty new to both WPF, MVVM and, of course, know almost nothing about `Caliburn`. I have read plenty of questions and answers about the `Caliburn` usage and now trying to use what I've learnt so far in my application.

My questions are:

1. Does it sound okay with the above layered architecture?
2. In the application bootstrapper, is it correct that we can register all services that will later be used (like `EventAgreggator` (EA), `WindowManager` or extra security and validation services), and also all the concerned VMs? These should be injected into VM instances via constructors or so (supposed I'll be using SimpleContainer). So from any VM that are properly designed and instantiated, we can have these services ready to be used. If I understand correctly, `Caliburn` and its `IoC` maintain a kind of global state so that different VMs can use and share it.
3. Navigation: I know this topic has been discussed so many times. But just to be sure I'm doing the right way: There'd be a `ShellViewModel` acting as the main window for the whole application with different VMs (or screens) loaded dynamically. Each VM can inherit either `Screen` or `ViewModelBase` or `NotifyChangedBase`. When I'm in, let's say, `VM A` and want to switch to `VM B`. I'd from inside `VM A` send a message (using EA) to the `ShellViewModel`, saying that I want to change to B. `ShellViewModel` receives the message and reloads its `CurrentViewModel` property. What should be a proper data structure to maintain the list of VMs to be loaded? How can stuffs like `Conductor` or `WindowManger` come into the place?
4. Can/Should `Caliburn` in one way or another support the access to the database (via EF). Or this access should be exposed to VM and/or BL only?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> Different from a conventional MVVM-based application, I add a business layer (BL) below the ViewModel (VM) layer

That's the standard case. ViewModels can't/shouldn't contain business logic which is considered to be part of the Model (Model in MVVM is considered a layer, not an object or data structure) in the MVVM. ViewModel is for presentation logic only.

1. Yes, as long as your Business (Domain) Layer has no dependency on the DAL (no reference to it's assembly). Repository interfaces should be defined in the Business Layer, their implementations in the Data Access Layer.
2. Yes, Bootstrapper is where you build your object graph (configuration the IoC container).

   Registering ViewModels: Depends on IoC framework. Some frameworks let you resolve unregistered types, as long as they are not abstract or interfaces (i.e. Unity). Not sure about Caliburn, haven't used it. If the IoC supports it, you don't need to register them.
3. One possible way to do it. I prefer navigation services though, works better for passing around parameters to views and windows that are not yet instantiated and you always know there is exactly one objects handling it.

   With messages, there could be 0, 1 or many objects listening to it. Up to you
4. What do you mean with support access to the database? You can use it to inject your repositories and/or services into your ViewModels, other than that there isn't much DB related stuff to it.